# how can i iterate through my object and display table rows in format

Tags: javascript

I have to use the .getJson method to download a file and display it on the page. I need help displaying rows in tables format,  my code displays but its all over the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
        var topSpot = '';

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            $("table").append("<tr>");
            $("table").append("<td>" + value.name + "</td>");
            $("table").append("<td>" + value.description + "</td>");
            $("table").append("<td>" + value.link + "</td>");

            var link = 'https://www.google.com/maps?q=' + value.location[0] + ',' +
                value.location[1];

            topSpot += '<td>' + '<a class="btn" href="' + link + '">Google Maps 
            location</a > ' + '</td > '; 

            topSpot += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#table').append(topSpot);
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to think of the DOM as a tree, not as a sequence of HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can achieve results I think a little easier to read. Please consider the following example.

Edit: In order to use $.getJSON in the implementation, I edited the answer, I am getting data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ for simplicity. The logic is almost the same. The difference here is to execute the render logic inside a $.getJSON callback.

```js
function render() {
    $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(data) {
      const output = document.querySelector('#output');
      const rows = data.map(toTableRows).join('');

      output.innerHTML = `<table>
        <tbody>${rows}</tbody>
      </table>`;
    });
}

function toTableRows(data) {
  return `
      <tr>
          <td>${data.title}</td>
          <td>${data.body}</td>
      </tr>`;
}

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very Good example, but I need to use the .getjson to download a file, then populate the data stored in it, my outcome should be in table row  format

Answer (score 0):

I think major reason its all over the page is lack of correct css classes getting applied on the html table that you are generating. To Fix Create the div container with right type of properties and place the table inside it using $('#table').append(topSpot) and also apply css on table elements. There are multiple plugins which provides controlled table output with multiple features like sorting, searching, editing and so on e.g. http://tabulator.info/ or simple plugin like jsontotable which you can explore,

```
<div id="jsontotable" class="jsontotable"></div>

var data = [{'Title1': 'Hello', 'Title2': 'Fine', 'Title3': 'Thank you'}, {'Title1': 'Hello', 'Title2': 'Fine', 'Title3': 'Thank you'}];
$.jsontotable(data, { id: '#jsontotable', header: false });
```

Comment: I tried your advice but couldn't get it to work. maybe I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: See my code displays but i cant seem to get it to display in the correct format! My code is al over the page